# Screen not refreshing in XNA Project

Tags: c#, winforms, xna

I'm using winforms with xna.
Everything's working so far except for the drawing. This is the initial code I had:

```
        protected override void Draw()
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            tileSheet.Draw(spriteBatch);
            foreach (Image img in selector)
                img.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
```

I placed a breakpoint and it is calling the draw method but nothing is changing on the screen but when I do this:

```
protected override void Draw()
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        tileSheet.Draw(spriteBatch);
        foreach (Image img in selector)
            img.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        Invalidate();
    }
```

It works! but the problem is that everything gets frozen and it seems to get caught up in an Invalidate loop. But why does the latter work but not to former? I've been working at this for hours now and I can't understand what's going wrong :/.

I feel like it's something simple but I can't wrap my head around it.

I've also tried Update and Refresh and they don't work either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalidate doesn't load unless repeated? (Winforms and Xna)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907657/invalidate-doesnt-load-unless-repeated-winforms-and-xna)

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate calls Draw<sup>1</sup>, so with the Invalidate in the mix, Invalidate -> Draw -> Invalidate -> Draw -> ..

The "fix" is to *not* Invalidate in the draw. Instead, only call Invalidate in response to *input* that would require a [re]draw. In the case of the "non working" (but really, it works!) former, make sure to call Invalidate *as appropriate* - but from outside the draw handler.

---

<sup>1</sup> Invalidate calls Draw "at some point later" but is an asynchronous action. It effectively posts a message that the WinForms process handles in the window message loop, then calls OnPaint which finally calls Draw. However, calling Invalidate from Draw will result in "too many updates too soon".

Comment: I understand how invalidate works. I have this in my Initialize method. Application.Idle += delegate { Invalidate(); }; and it does indeed call the draw method but nothing gets updated unless I place it in the draw method. That's my problem

Comment: Invalidate is doing it's job by calling the draw method but nothing is being drawn to the screen. The only time something gets drawn is if I also put Invalidate in my draw method.

Comment: @CodingMadeEasy Then it sounds like Invalidate is not being called as appropriate - i.e. the idle event handler is never firing. Put a breakpoint in there. Also try with a button that calls Invalidate. Using Refresh is *not* appropriate because that doesn't even go out to the message queue! That is, calling Refresh from Draw will *always* freeze/crash.

Comment: The idle event is firing. It's triggering the Invalidate event which is triggering the draw method. It goes through the draw method but nothing happens on the screen. When I put invalidate in the draw method then I see results but it freezes everything else.

Comment: Odd, I'm out of items: good luck! Consider updating the original post including the information in your comments above.